# ImmersiveFocusNotification Message hangs the application

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-desktop

I have a couple of application both are built in **Visual studio 2015**, One works fine but other hangs, when tried with **SPY++** came to know that behavior changes after system message:

> ImmersiveFocusNotification

Comment: What are the applications you are create? Did you create UWP apps?

Comment: No, Actually I ported both the application to VS2015 earlier it was created in VS2013.